# Static template member function as interrupt service routine

Tags: c++, templates, interrupt, avr

In the following class Mapper the static member function timer0CompA serves as an interrupt service routine. It gets the name "__vector_14" in the interrupt vector.

```
struct Mapper {
    static void timer0CompA() __asm__("__vector_14") __attribute__((__signal__, __used__, __externally_visible__));  
};
void Mapper::timer0CompA(){}
```

If I try to use the same approch with a template class

```
template<typename T>
struct Mapper {...};
```

the template member function is not inserted into the interrupt vector.

I know that this would be problematic if it would work: different instantiations would get the same name in the assembler code and therefore we would get a double defined symbol. But in my case this would be useful ...

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

A run time solution, not exactly optimal:

1. Disable interrupts on the device.
2. Build up a array of interrupts that you will be using in the same format as the isr vector array.
3. Override the ISR flash section. Make sure you save unused sections of the flash page and write them back.
4. Re-enable interrupts on the device.

But as you need to write a whole flash page at a time you'll best off doing it all at once.

NOTE: You could find yourself accidentally overriding application code so make sure the function you use to perform the change is not in that section of flash and that you write back the sections of the page you don't use.

Answer (score 0):

gcc and clang both appear to be a bit inconsistent when it comes with using either `__asm__()` or `__attribute__((signal))` with class template member functions.

First `__asm__()`.

- GCC - Silently ignores `__asm()` for methods in a template class.  Has no effect at all as far as I can tell.  Both for static and non-static members.
- Clang - Honors it and will give the member the requested name in *all* instantiations of the template class.  This means you'll get a compilation error, multiple definitions with the same mangled name, if you instantiate the template more than once.

There is a method that works on both: `__asm()` in explicit specializations of template methods is honored by both gcc and clang.  And you can instantiate the template more than once by giving it a different __asm() name in each specialization.

Example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class foo {
    static void f();
    // We put the real code in _f, each specialization of f() will
    // just call _f() to avoid re-writing the code.
    static inline void _f() { /*code*/ };
};

// Can only add __asm to a declaration, not a definition
template <> void foo<int>::f() __asm("__vector_1");
template <> void foo<int>::f() { foo<int>::_f(); }

template <> void foo<char>::f() __asm("__vector_2");
template <> void foo<char>::f() { foo<char>::_f(); }
```

The above gets you methods with the proper mangled symbol name on both clang and gcc.  The actual method code in `_f()` will be inlined into `f()` so there isn't any cost for the extra function.

Next `__attribute__((signal/interrupt))`:

The attribute `signal` is only supported on AVR, and there's no Clang AVR on godbolt, so I used `interrupt`, which is also an ISR, but a slightly different kind from AVR "signal" type.

This is handled the same way on `__asm()`.  Gcc will silently ignore it on template class methods, while clang honors it.

So we can adjust the above example to make it work:

```cpp
template <> void foo<int>::f() __asm("__vector_1") __attribute__((interrupt));
template <> void foo<char>::f() __asm("__vector_2") __attribute__((interrupt));
```

There's another quirk with `__attribute__((used))`: If it's put in the class template, attempting the specialize the method fails.  It appears as if naming the class in the specialization is enough to define a "used" class method, then the specialization tries to define the same method again.  The solution is to only add the attribute in the specialization:

```cpp
// This fails
class bar {
    static void f() __attribute__((used));
};
template <> void bar<int>::f();

// error: explicit specialization of 'f' after instantiation
// template <> void bar<int>::f();
//                            ^
// implicit instantiation first required here
// template <> void bar<int>::f();
//                  ^

// This works
class bar {
    static void f();
};
template <> void bar<int>::f() __attribute__((used));
```

Comment: BTW: If you want to *compile* for AVR using clang you may use these options `-mmcu=atxmega256a3u --target=avr -nostdlib` ([works on godbold](https://godbolt.org/z/ojb51GcKW)). For *linking* one needs to use `avr-g++`, as a linker is not available yet for AVR clang (at least not in beginning of 2021).